# Excel VBA FormulaR1C1 Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that will insert a formula into a cell.
    `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(((R[0]C[-2]*R[0]C[-3])+(R[0]C[-5]*R[0]C[-6]))/(R[0]C[-3]*IF(R[0]C[-6]=0,1,R[0]C[-6]),)"`

I want it so that the last term `IF(R[0]C[-6]=0,1,R[0]C[-6]),)` to be equal to 1 if the condition is equal to 0.

When I run the the code, comes up with a Error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error.
Can someone please help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have bad parenthesizing. Try this:

```
=IFERROR(((RC[-2]*RC[-3])+(RC[-5]*RC[-6]))/(RC[-3]*IF(RC[-6]=0,1,RC[-6])),)
'                                                                      ^^^
```

Also drop useless `[0]` and make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]*RC[-3])+RC[-5]*RC[-6])/RC[-3]*IF(RC[-6]=0,1,RC[-6]),"""")"`

The problems I could see with your formula are that you had six opening brackets and only 5 closing and you didn't enter anything after the comma.
You can also write `R[0]` as just `R` meaning *This Row*.